# Finding a 2 by 2 normal matrix when 3 of the 4 entries are given

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification

Below is a problem I made up and did. I expected that I would find a normal matrix of the form specified in the problem but I did not. Is my answer right?

Problem:

Find all normal matrices of the form:
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
4 & x \\
\end{bmatrix} $$
where $x$ is any arbitrary real number.

Answer:

The transpose of the matrix we are given is:
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 4 \\
 2 & x \\
\end{bmatrix} $$
Since the matrix is normal we can setup the following equation and
then solve for $x$
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 2 \\
 4 & x \\
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 4 \\
2 & x \\
\end{bmatrix} &= \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 4 \\
2 & x \\
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
4 & x \\
\end{bmatrix} \\
\\
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 + 4 & 4 + 2x \\
 4 + 2x & 16 + x^2 \\
\end{bmatrix} &=
\begin{bmatrix}
17 & 2 + 4x \\
2 + 4x & 4 + x^2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
Now we can set up four equations. The first of which is:
$$ 1 + 4 = 17 $$
which has no solutions. Therefore, I claim that there no normal matrix of the form:
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 4 \\
 2 & x \\
\end{bmatrix} $$
Am I right?

Comment: Following the definition of normal matrix, it seems right to me